# Validation on button click and change controller view iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9, ibaction

I'm new to Swift iOS development and I'm creating a user sign in page and when they click on the `Sign In` button, there is some validation performed on user input and if successful, send the user to a new page. In storyboard, I have two view controllers, the sign in page and the page after signing in successfully. I have created a segue from the `Sign In` button on the sign in page to the second page. Here is the following code.

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let username = usernameField.text, let password = passwordField.text else {
        return
    }
    if (username.isEmpty && password.isEmpty) {
        displayAlert(message: "username and password are not set")
        return
    }
    if (username.isEmpty) {
        displayAlert(message: "username is not set")
        return
    }
    if (password.isEmpty) {
        displayAlert(message: "password is not set")
        return
    }
}
```

This code works and successfully sends the user to the correct page after signing in. But when I add in an alert that says `"Success"`, the new page isn't loaded after the alert is closed. Here is the code that adds the alert for logging in successfully. The code is added right after the final conditional in the function `loginAction`.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Sucessfully logged in", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What's the reason why I'm not being sent to the new page with this alert? If the `"Success"` alert is commented out, I'm sent to the correct page.

I'm using `Xcode 9` and `Swift 4`.

Edit: Here is the class of the code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let username = usernameField.text, let password = passwordField.text else {
            return
        }
        if (username.isEmpty && password.isEmpty) {
            displayAlert(message: "username and password are not set")
            return
        }
        if (username.isEmpty) {
            displayAlert(message: "username is not set")
            return
        }
        if (password.isEmpty) {
            displayAlert(message: "password is not set")
            return
        }
        login(info: username)
        // self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // self.present(self, animated: true) {
        //     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Sucessfully logged in with \(username)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        //     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        //     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    private func login(info: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Sucessfully logged in with \(info)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        // alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in self.dismiss(animated: true) })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func displayAlert(message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you don't wait till the user selects an action.  Use the completion closure.

Comment: I did something like this with the completion closure but nothing. Thanks for telling me to use the closure but how to dismiss and load the page correctly like before? That would be helpful. `alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in self.dismiss(animated: true) }`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed to do in order to get it to work properly. I updated my function `loginAction`.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Sucessfully logged in with \(info)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { action in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: nil)
})
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```